# Flutter syncfusion_flutter_calendar how to get appointments list of a specific day

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm using `syncfusion_flutter_calendar` package it's a package which give you a lot of UI examples, open source code, and code examples. I used calendar example in which I can add a list of appointment with date duration and some specific information in a margin of date I can get the date after clicking in it, but the problem is that I can not get appointments list of a specific clicked date.

package link
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar
git hub app link

https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/tree/master/lib
[example of appointment in a specific date which I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzaiO.png)